# Syntax highlighting for files containing a mix of PHP and HTML5 in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

Which colour schemes are suited to files that contain a mix of PHP and HTML5 (like you'd find in WordPress theme files)?

If you can, recommend for SASS as well please. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Railcasts](https://gist.github.com/1659369), which has been looking pretty good. This one is a version of [Monokai](https://gist.github.com/1948289)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Clouds is a very popular color scheme, it's quite nice too, in my opinion... :)

http://fredhq.com/projects/clouds